# What are norms in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I don't understand what they are, and would really appreciate a simple explanation showing what value they bring to the world without too much implementation detail of how they work.

Comment: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/What-are-norms-td540857.html

Comment: @MattBall: Doesn't seem to say much.

Comment: downside to using norms is extra memory needed for searching (I think it is exactly one byte per field per document.. so let's say all docs have same 20 fields, 1 million docs means about 1B*20*1000000 = approx 20MB memory allocated just for norms). downside to disabling norms is you can't do field and doc boosting. So if you are indexing a relational database with just a bunch of short fields, you may not care about norms and can disable to reduce memory needed during searching. But when I index RDBMS data I leave norms enabled.. memory is cheap, and often need to index comment columns, etc

Answer (score 15):

A norm is part of the calculation of a score.  The norm could be calculated however you like, really.  The main thing that sets the norm apart, is it's calculated at index-time.  Generally, other factors influencing score are calculated at query time, based on how well the document matches the query.  The `norm` saves on query performance by being stored along with the document, instead.

The standard implementation can be found, and well described, in Lucene's [TFIDFSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html).  There, it is the product of the set field boost (or the product of all fields boosts, if multiple have been set on the field) and "lengthNorm" (which is a calculated factor designed to weigh matches on shorter documents more heavily).  Neither of these is dependent on the makeup of the query, and so are good choices to be calculated and stored at index time instead.

They are then stored in a compressed, and highly lossy, single-byte format (with approx. 1 significant decimal digit of accuracy).

Comment: Thanks but I don't really get you. I want to know what a norm is, what problem it solves. This is more of an implementation detail as far as I can tell. Imagine me as someone not very clever :)

Comment: Precisely what it does it up to the implementation.  I applies scoring logic to a field which is independent of the particular query.  In the default implementation, it applies field boosts, and boosts hits on shorter fields to have higher relevance than longer fields (the thinking being that 2-out-of-10 is usually more relevant than 2-out-of-1000)

Answer (score 8):

When you index, process, your source information you will treat some documents and fields as more important than others.

For example, the task is to spy on your colleagues' emails. A word match in the title field is more important than a word match in the body field. We do this by multiplying the number of matches in the title field by a number larger than we use for body field matches.

#### Example Indexable Email Records

```
+----+-------------+--------------+
| ID | Title       | Body         |
|----+-------------+--------------|
| 7  | Back Monday | Ben was sick |
| 8  | I'm sick    | cover for me |
| 9  | Help        | I am stuck   |
+----+-------------+--------------+
```

So, searching for 'sick' and multiplying a title match by 4 and body match by 2 and ordering highest score first - the documents are ranked ID 8 first and ID 7 second (see table 1 below).

#### Table 1: Matches for the word 'sick' ordered by score (descending)

```
+----+---------+--------+-----------------------+
| Id | Title   | Body   | Score                 |
|    | Matches | Matches|                       |
|----+---------+--------+-----------------------|
| 8  | 1       | 0      | (1 * 4) + (0 * 2) = 4 |
| 7  | 0       | 1      | (0 * 4) + (1 * 2) = 2 |
+----+---------+--------+-----------------------+
```

These numbers, 4 and 2, we are multiplying the matches with are the *norms*.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ID 8 first (as it has the term 'sick' in the title) and then ID 7 second (the term is in the body)?

Comment: Edited Answer: Yes, thanks for the correction! How many people did I confuse?

Comment: @notapatch *the documents are ranked ID 9 first and ID 8 second*, 9 should be 8 and 8 should be 7.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that Jason. Updated!