# Methods usage of org.apache.lucene.document.Field class of Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I try to understand two methods of the title class i.e Field. Here is method which contains those two methods.

```
protected void addAnalyzedField(Document document, String fieldName, TokenStream tokenizer,
            boolean withNorms, boolean withTermFreqAndPositions) {
        Field field = new Field(fieldName, tokenizer);
        field.setOmitNorms(!withNorms);
        field.setOmitTermFreqAndPositions(!withTermFreqAndPositions);
        document.add(field);
    }
```

I was absolutely confused for `field.setOmitNorms(boolean....)` and `field.setOmitTermFreqAndPositions(boolean....)` that what these two methods really does? I was guessing that these method are used whether the field are omitted from/to indexing process. Am I right?

Can anybody can show up with some practical scenarios?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to store the field without indexing, simply use [StoredField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StoredField.html). If other fields on the same document will get indexed and point to this document during the search, you will be able to retrieve the same value as you presented.

Norms are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536021/what-are-norms-in-lucene).

Term frequencies allow to tell how many matching terms have been found in the index.

Comment: If you feel like the answer was satisfying, you might want to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as this is how this site works. Thank you!

Comment: You mean that using Field class, all available fields on the document will get indexed? and Not any things be left without indexing? Please!

Comment: Fields can be indexed or stored, or both. You have the full control over this by picking the right field type. If you index a field, it will be searchable. If you store a field, it can later be retrieved - Lucene can work as a storage system as well. You choose what you want.

Comment: Actually, I have legacy code which have array list which holds string values. It is said that the array list is used for indexing in such a way that all of the values of array list is not used for indexing but some are used. So I wonder that in this scenario, is it possible that some content of array list not to be indexed? Please share if you have any relevant.

Comment: You might want to open a new question for this and provide relevant code.