# What is the difference between query time boost and field boost in lucene 6.0.1?

Tags: java, lucene

Actually I know about the field boost a little bit, but I also want to know the purpose of providing the method **BoostQuery(Query query, float boost),** why we need this method? And how can we use it? Please follow the link for method BoostQuery() details [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BoostQuery.html)

Please follow this link to download the code sample of Different Queries implemented of different conditions from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vzowlktx77xui1r/Queries.zip?dl=0)

Now I don't exactly understand that how I can boost a query? Or I can only boost query with multiple queries running at the same time? (because in the provided code sample each query runs at a single time).

Please let me know if you don't understand anything.

Code sample is running on "IntelliJ IDEA the Java IDE"

Libraries have been added in "lib" folder. Also add them before running.

So in simple words again I need to know;

1. What's the purpose of providing the method BoostQuery() while we have field.setBoost() and query.setBoost()?
2. How to use it?
3. And also how I can use query.setBoost()?
4. Is there also a difference between query.setBoost() and BoostQuery()?

Answer (score 1):

Field boosts are set at index time, and are stored in the [field norm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536021/what-are-norms-in-lucene).  `BoostQuery` allows you too apply a boost at query time, generally when combining multiple queries in a `BooleanQuery` or something like that.

`Query.setBoost()` is no longer available.  It has been replaced by `BoostQuery`, because [queries were made immutable in 6.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6531).

Comment: thanks @femtoRgon but is there any code sample which i can use to understand for BoosQuery(), that how it works?

Comment: @WasifHafeez - I thought about adding one, but wasn't really sure what you want demonstrated.  It's pretty simple to use.  Just call the ctor with the query to boost, and how much you want to boost it, like:  `new BoostQuery(mySubQuery, 5.0f)`.  What is it you don't get about how to use it?

Comment: did you check the sample code i provided? i want to implement BoostQuery in that code sample. there are different queries but only 1 run at each time, so tell me if there is any way to run multiple(more than 1) queries to boost one of them.? thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @WasifHafeez - No, I didn't. If the code there is relevant, you should have it in the question.